# "jobs.job_id" not same datatype as the referencing column "job_history.job_id" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have 2 tables with same column names and same datatype
`jobs.jobs_id` and `job_history.job_id`.

This is the SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs
(
    job_id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    job_title VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
    min_salary DECIMAL (8, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    max_salary DECIMAL (8, 2) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE job_history 
(
    employee_id int not null,
    start_date date not null,
    end_date date not null,
    job_id varchar(10),
    department_id int not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES jobs (job_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments (department_id)
);
```

As shown above, they both have the same datatype.

When I run the 1st table code, it runs without any error. and when I run the job_history table, I get an error

> Column 'jobs.job_id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'job_history.job_id' in foreign key 'FK__job_histo__job_i__34E8D562'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

There are no previous errors in the code except this. So what am I missing?

Comment: Are the column collations different?

Comment: Your DML is fine. Do double check that column definition as as what you describe here

Comment: no column collations are the same. I just checked.

Comment: the `job` table in your database must be different from the DML that you have posted here (sp_help table to verify). Try drop and re-create the `job` table

Comment: I am new to SQL and just practicing. So I deleted the database and copy pasted the same code in a new database. It works now. I didn't get what you said though.

Answer (score 0):

When i execute the following, i don't get any error:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs
(
    job_id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    job_title VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
    min_salary DECIMAL (8, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    max_salary DECIMAL (8, 2) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employees 
(
    employee_id int PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE departments
(
    department_id   int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE job_history 
(
    employee_id int not null,
    start_date date not null,
    end_date date not null,
    job_id varchar(10),
    department_id int not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES jobs (job_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments (department_id)
);
```